# Event of Digest Cancel Button in Browser

Tags: java, events, button, shiro, cancel-button

I need to write an action to cancel button of the digest in the browser(SHIRO).

Comment: Hey!
Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, or what you have already tried.

Comment: do you Know shiro Basicauth?